# I can't get the value of refile.rb fron setting.yml in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, refile

I would like to call value of setting.yml in config/initializers/refile.rb
So I try to set it as follows.But it Does not work as I thought.

When I run SPEC file, the value of Refile.cdn_host is empty.
I don't know well why this value is empty.
can I get some advice?

config/settings/test.yml

```
cloudfront:
 host: 'localhost'
```

config/initializers/refile.rb

```
Refile.cdn_host = Settings.cloudfront.host
```

Incidentally when I change it as follows,

```
Refile.cdn_host = 'localhost'
```

it does work without being empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the file first, try

```
Refile.cdn_host = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/settings/test.yml")['cloudfront']['host']
```